# Error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions while using bsxfun in matlab

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

My code is :

```
A =[1 5 8; 3 4 7;9 10 11]
B = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,sum(A));
```

On running, I get an error : `index exceeds matrix dimension`

Please help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code executes without error.

Comment: Also can't reproduce.  This code runs as expected (at least for me).

Comment: Clear the variable `sum` from your workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (very likely) defined a variable called `sum` in your workspace. `clear` it, rename it, and you'll be fine.

```
A =[1 5 8; 3 4 7;9 10 11];
B = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,sum(A))
B =

   0.076923   0.263158   0.307692
   0.230769   0.210526   0.269231
   0.692308   0.526316   0.423077


sum = 5;   %% Oops!

B = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,sum(A))
Error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions
```

Comment: and that's why it's a bit silly to use `()` for functions calls and arrays...oh matlab